# How can i add the date format for disable the button from 4pm-9:45am

Tags: javascript, php

**Here is the code**

```
<div class="col-auto">
    <br>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="show-button" name="punchin" onclick="showHidden(); showbttHidden();">Punch In</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" id="hide-button" name="punchout" onclick="showHidden(); showbttHidden();">Punch Out</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

In this code, how can i make a logic in date so that i can disbale the butoon between 4pm to 9:45am

```
<script>

var h = new Date().getHours();

if (h >= 1 && h <= 8) {
    document.getElementById('show-button').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('hide-button').disabled=true;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: When button will be disabled? Automatic or on page refresh?

Comment: I would suggest doing it on the backend, you can disable the button with javascript but it won't protect it from being clicked.

Comment: I swear I saw this same question recently. Probably deleted their other account.

Comment: should showbttHidden() be showbtnHidden() ?

Comment: On page refresh @RohitRasela

Comment: Plus, how is this a php question?

Comment: @Atomzwieback that suggestive edit of yours https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21681316 doesn't improve the question here at all, plus, you even made a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This will enable the button between 9:45AM and 4PM.

```
    var UTC_hours = new Date().getHours();
    var UTC_minutes = new Date().getMinutes();

    if (UTC_hours >= 10 && UTC_hours < 16){
        document.getElementById('show-button').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('hide-button').disabled = false;
    }
    else if(UTC_hours == 9 && UTC_minutes >= 45 && UTC_hours < 16){
        document.getElementById('show-button').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('hide-button').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('show-button').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('hide-button').disabled = true;
    }
```

Please Note: This is JavaScript which can be disabled on the users side because it is client side code. Add a check on the server side to verify the time if they are not supposed to be toggled between 4pm and 9:45am

Comment: @Saad its client side code. It will go off whatever current time your user is at.